# Flutter - Operation not permitted (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins

I am trying to run my app in iOS, But constantly getting these errors for multiple plugin. Not sure what's the problem and there is no specific instruction for iOS for these plugins. Please let me know if anyone faces same problem.

```
error: open /Users/vikasp/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-0.6.3+3/ios/Classes/SharePlugin.h: Operation not permitted (in target 'share' from project 'Pods')

error: open /Users/vikasp/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/connectivity-0.4.5+6/ios/Classes/ConnectivityPlugin.h: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: please try this https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2365#issuecomment-51456270

Comment: @chunhunghan  , Here "sudo chown -R username:staff projectFolder" do I need to add only iOS project path from flutter or my full flutter project path and which username do I need to add?

Comment: @chunhunghan, I tried the above solution but it is not working for me.

Comment: I have deleted the previous one and cloned project. Now I am not facing this error.

Answer (score 3):

Give your *Xcode* full disk access through *System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access* and mark *Xcode*.

If this is not the case, [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43659) is another related issue to this.